# percentage in classify of learning algorithem

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm using weka, I have a training set, and the classify of the examples in the training set is boolean.
After I have the training set, I want to predict the percentage of new input to be true or false. I want to get a number between 0-1, and not only o or 1.

How can I do that, I have seen that in the prediection there are only the possibels classifes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only make the same kind of prediction with the learned classifier -- it learns to make the predictions you train it to make. The kind of prediction you want sounds more like regression. That is, you're don't want a strict classification, but a continuous value designating the membership probability.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to replace the Booleans in your training set with 0/1 values and learn a regression model. This will give you numbers, although not necessarily only between 0 and 1.

To get real probabilities, you would need to use a classifier that calculates probabilities (such as Naive Bayes) and write some custom code (using the Weka library) to retrieve them. See [the javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html#distributionForInstance%28weka.core.Instance%29) of the method that gives you access to the class probabilities.

Comment: I change the classify to numeric, and it return number between 0-1 as I want. But does thoes numbers means, if i get 0.89 that means that it was very close to be classify as 1?

Comment: That's more or less open to your interpretation. Yes, numbers closer to one mean that it's more like a class one thing, but whether you say that it *is* class one at 0.6 or 0.9 is up to you.

Comment: If all the examples are o or 1, does it possible that weka will classify some new input with a number which significant far from 0 and 1. for instance could he classify new input as 8?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It depends on the model that you learn. In general though the predictions of *good* models will be not be far outside the [0,1] range.